# Xcode segue leads to back screen sometimes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, segue

I have two view controllers that are linked to each other via segues. Both segues are modal, and have identifiers. Both view controllers have storyboard IDs and titles. When I go to my second view controller (VC2) I sometimes get a completely black screen (except for, strangely, a UILabel which has its text updated by a NSTimer every second). I have to check/uncheck animated on the segue several times to get it to work again. I have no idea why this is happening. I tried switching the views programmatically, and the problem went away, but I'd prefer to use less code and I have to share data between the segues. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: It sounds like you have a slightly unusual setup with two view controllers linked to each other by seperate modal segues. Usually one VC would act as the parent and would launch the other via a modal segue. The modal VC would use an unwind segue to return to the parent.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about that. Tried it though, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Managed to fix it. The UILabel that would show up under the black screen had a bad IBOutlet. I deleted that outlet and fixed it, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either try what Calvdeos is saying
2. Or Use Navigation controller. Push first VC in the navigation controller. Then upon user action, push second VC on top of it. Then when VC2 is done, pop it off the VC stack.

It really depends on what the flow is. If you expand on the logical flow, i can suggest better.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried both of the above, but still get the problem. Any clue what the underlying cause could be? On my secondviewcontroller's viewDidLoad I initialize several ints and bools, and start a timer and start playing music.